Splitting a scoping review by themes
I am on a team with 2 others in completing a scoping review. The journal that invited us to submit the article has a word limit of 4000 words. Therefore, we split it by themes identified in the results section - we had identified 2 main themes with each having subthemes. The methodology and strengths/limitations will be the same since we are using the same question and objective for both. How is it recommended to reference the same information since it has not changed? The first article has not been published but has been submitted and we want to get the second submitted asap. Both will be submitted to the same journal.

You can discuss this with the editor; they should be able to answer definitively for the journal. Since your articles were invited, the editor should be willing to clarify such matters.
In principle, though, I would think that each published article should generally stand alone; each should have its own complete methodology and objectives section, for at least two reasons:

If the articles are being submitted and reviewed independently, one might be accepted while the other might be rejected. So, you cannot assume that one should be able to reference the other.
Even if both are published, normally you should not require readers interested in one article on a theme of interest to read another article on a theme of lesser interest just to obtain essential information like the methodology and objectives of the article they like.

All that said, I note that 4000 words are quite a low limit for a review article. If the article was indeed invited, I would request the editor to allow you 8000 words for a single joint article. Even that woudl be quite a short limit for a review article.
